# App not showing on test-flight of iPad

Tags: ios, testflight

I uploaded my app on iTunes. My app is universal, for iPad and iPhone.
On iPhone test-flight it is showing but on iPad test-flight it is not showing. What is the reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the same Apple ID on that device - you should re-add account to testers in iTunes Connect, then open e-mail with link to the application on that iPad and open the link.

If you are using another Apple ID - just add it to testers in iTunes Connect and proceed as above.

Comment: How to re-add account to tester?

Comment: Delete from testers list, then add again

Comment: actually it is my developer account.

Comment: It does not matter

Comment: I have re-added account still same issue

Comment: Open itunesconnect, go to My Apps, select your app, open Testflight tab, choose internal or external testing section (depends on how you're using testflight), then tap edit above the list of users

Comment: Did you received new email with invitation to install app via Testflight? Did you open it on the iPad?